# Communication between 2 collection views

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm developing an app that will look like this :

[image]

As explained on the picture above, I need to update the second collection view based on the filters selected on the first collection view.

**First question:**

I decided to use 2 container view that manages their own collectionVCs, is this a good architecture to you ? I've seen some people using only one delegate for multiple collection views but I'm looking for a high level of customization and could determine wether my approach or theirs is better.

**Second question:**

The second collection view's section headers name are the same as the selected filters on the first collection view.

Dummy Example:

Let's say I have filters "Sea", "Land", "Air" in the first collection view, I want the second to display cells of animals that live in the selected "area".

**How can I implement this ?** I think I will have to use NSNotifications to handle communication between my 2 collection views but I don't know if this is the best approach.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**First Question**

1. If you have taken the two `collectionView` Separately, still you
   define the `datasource` as the same `ViewController`.
2. So you need supply the data in the same `datasource` method.
3. To differentiate between the `collectionView` you can either compare
       reference or tag.

**Second Question**

4. You can achieve this without using `NSNotification`
5. First thing to do is, you need take reference of lower
   `collectionView` using `IBOulet`.
6. On in `DidSelect` of first Collection you need to update the array
   & reload the lower `collectionview` using that reference.

Comment: I can't hold an IBOutlet because I have 2 separate CollectionViewControllers